A basic question about two consecutive critical points
Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a differential function such that $f'$ is continues on $[a,b]$. I addition, suppose that $x_1,x_2\in(a,b)$ are the only two critical points in $[a,b]$, that is, $f'(x_1)=f'(x_2)=0$ and $f'(x)\neq0$ for $x\notin[a,b]\setminus\{x_1,x_2\}$. I want to prove that if $x_1$ is local maximum, then $f(x_2)<f(x_1)$.
My attempt: Assume by contradiction that $f(x_2)\geq f(x_1)$ and without loss of generality that $x_1<x_2$. Note that by our assumption $f'(x)\neq 0$ for each $x\in(x_1,x_2)$. Moreover, either $f'(x)>0$ for each $x\in(x_1,x_2)$ or $f'(x)<0$ for each $x\in(x_1,x_2)$, since otherwise, if $f'(y_1)>0$ and $f'(y_2)<0$ for $x_1<y_1<y_2<x_2$, then by the continuity of $f'$, it would follows that $f'(c)=0$ for some $c\in(y_1,y_2)$, a contradiction. Now, note that there exists $\xi\in(x_1,x_2)$ such that
$$
f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}.
$$
Since $f(x_2)\geq f(x_1)$ and $x_1<x_2$, it follows that $f'(\xi)>0$, so $f'(x)>0$ for $x\in(x_1,x_2)$. Therefore, $f$ is strictly increasing in $(x_1,x_2)$. Thus $f(x_1)<f(x)$ for every $x_1<x$, which contradicts the fact that $x_1$ is a local maximum.
Does this proof is correct? if so, does there a more simple proof?

Do you know the extreme value theorem?

Thanks @Sine of the Time. Maybe, What this theorem claims?

you can take a look here

what happens if  $x_1>x_2$?

I can not assume that $x_1<x_2$ without loss of generality?

You right. I will fix it. Regarding the WLOG, I get a strictly decreasing function, so $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$, a contradiction,

Suppose $x_1<x_2$ (the case $x_1>x_2$ is similar) and consider the interval $[x_1,x_2]$. Since $f'(x)$  is continuous and $f'(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in ]x_1,x_2[$, $f$ is strictly increasing or decreasing. But since $x_1$ is a local maximum, $f(x_1)>f(x)$ for all $x \in ]x_1,x_1+\varepsilon[$ for some $\varepsilon>0$. Hence $f$ is decreasing and $f(x_2)<f(x_1)$.
